# Using -ss and -to to play a video using ffplay

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to display the video before trimming it

to trim we can use 2 ways:

method 1:

```
FFmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.000 -to 00:00:15.000 output.mp4
```

This Generates a video of length 5 seconds [Note here to is used we can also use -t]

method 2

```
FFmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:00:5.000 output.mp4
```

This Generates a video of length 5 seconds[here we used -t so we specify duration]

If I want to display a video I'm using

```
FFplay -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:5
```

but its starting video from 5 sec and to 15 sec [video length being 10 sec where it should be 10 sec to 15 sec [5 secs]]

and if the file format is different again its starting at random points like for .mkv its stating at 8 sec to 15 sec
if im using -to im getting this error

```
Failed to set value '00:00:15.123' for option 'to': Option not found
```

im testing this from past 1 hr some one clear me how can i do ffplay for a trimming video
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the issue with only that file which i used
for any other files is working fine with this command

```
FFplay -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:5
```

Comment: Too bad it won't accept the other related argument like `ffmpeg` does though =/: `Failed to set value '00:10' for option 'to': Option not found`
Version 4.4